# Como fazer uma matriz no R que suas entradas sejam iguais a i * j?

Tags: r, matriz

Quero uma matriz generica `10x10`, que suas entradas sejam iguais a `i*j`, onde `i` é a coluna e `j` a linha

Comment: Oi felipe, bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor esclareça melhor sua dúvida, mostre o que já sabe/já tentou e o que falta saber. Não conheço R, mas sua dúvida pode significar várias coisas: "ele não sabe criar uma lista?" "ele não sabe criar uma matriz de tamanho X?" "ele sabe criar mas não consegue por os valores desejados nela?" etc. Colocando mais **contexto** na pergunta fica mais fácil te ajudar, e sua pergunta provavelmente será melhor recebida no site (normalmente esperamos um entendimento mínimo do assunto, ainda que sejamos receptivos a perguntas de nível iniciante).

Comment: @mgibsonbr acho que não tem necessidade de fechar essa questão, por mais que não esteja perfeita, não há muito mistério em como montar uma matriz `10x10` com elementos `i*j` como podemos ver nas respostas.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli Concordo! Não votei pra fechar, e dadas as boas respostas estou disposto a reabri-la caso fechem.

Comment: A pergunta pode não ser extensa ou demonstrar uma pesquisa ou esforço anterior, mas está bem clara, pois é simples e objetiva. Talvez mereça os votos que recebeu, mas não concordo com o fechamento.

Answer (score 5):

Uma alternativa para aplicar uma função em todas combinações de 2 vetores é a função `outer()`. No caso:

```
 > outer(1:10, 1:10, '*')
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
 [2,]    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18    20
 [3,]    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27    30
 [4,]    4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36    40
 [5,]    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45    50
 [6,]    6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54    60
 [7,]    7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63    70
 [8,]    8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72    80
 [9,]    9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81    90
[10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100
```

Comment: Legal essa função, nunca tinha visto. Gostei desse jeito aqui tbm: `1:10 %o% 1:10`

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer isso assim:

```
> x <- matrix(rep(1:10, each = 10), ncol = 10, byrow = T)
> apply(x, 1, function(x) x*1:10)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
 [2,]    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18    20
 [3,]    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27    30
 [4,]    4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36    40
 [5,]    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45    50
 [6,]    6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54    60
 [7,]    7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63    70
 [8,]    8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72    80
 [9,]    9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81    90
[10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100
```

Primeiro crio uma matriz `x` com todas as linhas iguais ao vetor `1, 2, 3,.., 10`.
Em seguida usando a função `apply`, multiplico cada linha pelo vetor 1:10. Note que no R, quando você multiplica vetores, ele faz a multiplicação elemento por elemento, por isso essa conta funciona.

Uma outra maneira de fazer, seria criar a matriz `x` com todas as colunas sendo `1,2,3, .., 10`. E em seguida multiplicá-la pelo vetor 1:10. Isso também vai funcionar, mas é menos intuitivo pois depende de um conceito importante do R, chamado reciclagem.

```
x <- matrix(rep(1:10, each = 10), ncol = 10)
x*1:10
```

Como o @mgibsonbr comentou, nas póximas perguntas tente explicar um pouco mais o que você tentou, e exatamente o que você não está conseguindo.